# Unable to locate standard C++ libraries while compiling with clang++ and cuda sdk

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++, libstdc++

I am trying to compile a cuda program using clang++. I am following the instructions as provided at [Clang's Instructional Page](http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html).

However, when try to issue the compilation with the following command,

```
$ clang++ -v  -I $CUDA/samples/common/inc/ -L $CUDA/lib/ -I $CUDA/include/ axpy.cu -lcudart_static -lcuda -ldl -lrt -pthread -lstdc++
```

I am facing an error message saying:

```
In file included from /opt/cuda//samples/common/inc/helper_cuda.h:24:
/opt/cuda//samples/common/inc/helper_string.h:18:10: fatal error: 'fstream' file not
  found
#include <fstream>
         ^
```

Peculiarly, when I try to compile  a dummy program with the same library as a cc code, it goes through well, with out any error.

I am listing out version info below:

```
$ clang++ -v
clang version 3.7.1 (tags/RELEASE_371/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

I am currently using archlinux with cuda installed at `/opt/cuda`.

*UPDATE*:

I was able to get the compilation to move a bit further by explicitly setting `CPATH` to point to `CPATH=/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/:/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/:/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/:`

However, now I am facing other errors of the form:

```
/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/cwchar:146:11: error: no member named 'fwide' in the global
  namespace
using ::fwide;
    ~~^
```

Comment: I'm not an expert when it comes to CUDA, but do you desire to use GCC's standard lib (stdlib) or LLVM's (stdc++)? Tried omitting the `-lstdc++` paramter?

Comment: Hi  Torbjörn, I actually need to generate the AST for the kernel for my project for which I intend to use libclang, hence clang++ and CUDA.

Comment: @Torbjörn yes, infact I have tried three variations of the compilation, one without `-lstdc++` flag, one with it, and one with explicit mention of my `c++` library location at `/usr/include/c++` using `... -I/usr/include/c++`

Comment: Maybe you should install a cuda compatible gcc version to get a compatible libstdc++.

Comment: @MichaelHaidl The compilation seems to move a bit further when specify the flag `-D_GNU_SOURCES` (I figured that out by first adding `llvm-config --cxxconfig` flag to the clang command, and then manually figuring out which flag can get the code running.) I am also facing problem when I specify `-lpthread` flag. Since the approach doesn't look water tight to me, I have not posted it as an answer.

I will try to do what you've suggested. Thanks !